# How can I show that the quotient function to the real projective space is closed?

Tags: general-topology, projective-space

As I have to demonstrate that this space is a  Hausdorff space, obviously I hope to find a proof without the use of this fact

Comment: Which projective space? Which quotient function? If you just want a proof that $\mathbb{R}\mathrm{P}^n$ is Hausdorff, the easiest route is perhaps to display it as the orbit space of $\mathbb{Z} / 2$ acting on $S^n$ and then invoke a general result about orbit spaces of nice group actions.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming by quotient function, you mean the one from $S^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}P^n$? Regardless, it makes no difference to the outcome. The way that the quotient function/topology is defined gives you the result.

**Edit: As David pointed out, quotient maps are not always closed. However, due to the specifics of how $\mathbb{R}P^n$ is defined using the quotient, it actually is in this case. But then this is just restating the question. My comments about the CW complex still stands.**

If you are trying to show that $\mathbb{R}P^n$ is Hausdorff, you can construct a CW complex structure for it since any CW complex is Hausdorff. This may be simply moving the goal posts in your case though if you haven't seen this result yet. When I have time, I can find a link to another post on this site showing CW complexes are Hausdorff, there's bound to be at least 1.

Comment: This feels a bit misleading, as you seem to be claiming that all quotient maps are automatically closed, which they are not in general. It is certainly true in this case because of the specifics of how the quotient is defined, but it’s not just immediate from the fact that it is a quotient map.

Comment: @DavidGao yes, I did not mean to imply that quotient maps are always closed. That's my fault. The main substance of my comment was intended to be that regarding a CW structure. I will edit my comment to reflect this